# For the limit of a function is better the limit point definition or the adherent point definition?

Tags: limits, definition

In Rudin's PMA the autor gives the limit point definition, which is (not exactly quoted):

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces. Suppose $E$ is a subset of $X$, $f:E\rightarrow Y$, $p$ is a limit point of $E$ (in $X$) and $q\in Y$. We write $$\lim_{x\to p}{f(x)}=q$$ If for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x\in E$, $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$ implies $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$

In Lange's Undergraduate Analysis, the autor gives the adherent point definition, which generalized to metric spaces is:

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces. Suppose $E$ is a subset of $X$, $f:E\rightarrow Y$, $p$ is an adherent point of $E$ (in $X$) and $q\in Y$. We write $$\lim_{x\to p}{f(x)}=q$$ If for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x\in E$, $d_X(x,p)<\delta$ implies $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$

Note that the two definition are not equivalent, for if $f(x)=0$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$, then $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)}=0$$ in the limit point definition, while $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)}$$ does not exist in the adherent point definition. In my opinion is better the adherent point definition because you can always just restrict the domain of $f$ to not contain the point $p$, and you get the limit point definition. Morover, in stating the definition of continuity, for the adherent point defintion you simply require that $$(*)\ \ \ \lim_{x\to p}{f(x)}=f(p)$$ at every $p\in E$, while for the limit point definition you require that either $p$ be an isolated point of $E$, or $(*)$ holds, for every $p\in E$, which is a longer condition.

My question is, what are the dowsides (if any) of the adherent point definition, since it seems to me that most people don't use it.